# DAX max date in dimension ignore filters on date

Tags: powerbi, dax

In my Power BI model I have a fact table (factSales) that links to a date dimension (dimDate) through a surrogate key DateId.  Now I want to add a measure to obtain the max invoice date for each client.  But it should be the maximum date ignoring the context (for the date filters).  (So if I filter all sales in Q1 2020, then I still want the max invoice date in e.g. 2021).

This is how I got it working:

Add new column in factSales:

```
Invoice Date = RELATED(DimDate[Date])
```

Add new measure in factSales:

```
Last Contract = 

            CALCULATE(     MAX(FactSales[Invoice Date]),
                                    ALL( DimDate )
                                )
```

This works, but is there a better way to do this ?  Without the extra calculated column. (And without using both-directional filtering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CROSSFILTER inside CALCULATE:

```
Last Contract =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( Dates[Date] ),
    REMOVEFILTERS ( DimDate ),
    CROSSFILTER ( Sales[Date], Dates[Date], BOTH )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Last Contract =
CALCULATE ( MAX ( DimDate[Date] ), ALL ( DimDate ), FactSales )
```

This removes filtering from a slicer on `DimDate[Date]` by still applies `FactSales` as a filter table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure to return `max date` using the following dax formula:

```
Measure = MAX(Sheet1[Date])
```

To always display the latest date without filter by slicer, you need to click on the `slicer` then goto `Format >Edit Interaction >click none on the specific visual`. In the following case, the max date is still `8 Nov 21` even though the slicer latest date is `Sep 21`

[image]

Comment: The problem is that not only slicers can filter, but a table with a group by Year/Month for example will also filter my data.

Comment: I think it is because you have used `related` function, that it why it also filter your `scorecard`? I never need to use `related` until today, although in future I am not sure...When you have exclude the `slicer` to filter your table, then it wont changed value based on the slicer value as per my testing